# Oracle RAC: Can two transactions share an SCN?

Tags: oracle, rac

Under what conditions (if any) can two transactions share an SCN?

To put another way, is there a guarantee that if several DML statements share an SCN they are guaranteed to be part of the same transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two transactions won't share an SCN barring a bug in Oracle.

Exactly how Oracle ensures this varies by version, platform, and configuration settings.  For example, back in the Oracle 9.2 days, there was by default a non-zero `max_commit_propagation_delay` which meant that a row that was inserted on one node and committed might not be immediately visible to a query on the other node.  In that configuration, Oracle could use a [Lamport SCN generation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/rac.920/a96597/coord.htm#21696) algorithm where SCN's were generated in parallel without a need for internode communication.  In 10.1 and later, a [broadcast on commit strategy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixlrPltZHKAhUCUD4KHQoBCJcQFghbMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.juliandyke.com%2FPresentations%2FRACInternals.ppt&usg=AFQjCNEgyW8gwaeef-ijtqc3dGn5cPvxAA&sig2=GqybLwXXsCr3zH1ha909_Q) (link is to a PPT presentation from Julian Dyke which is excellent but may be bigger than you'd expect) is used instead and `max_commit_propagation_delay` defaults to 0 (no idea what happens if you use 10.1 and set a non-default `max_commit_propagation_delay`-- that might well flip back to Lamport).